# Normal UpdatePanel behaviour? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Am I doing this correctly?

I have two dropdowns. The first is populated on form load, and it is a trigger for an updatepanel that contains the 2nd dropdown.

When I change the value in the first dropdown box, it triggers the 2nd one's updatepanel, which populates it.

However, when I select a value in the 2nd dropdownbox, it triggers itself and repopulates... so if I select the 2nd or 3rd item in the dropdown, it repopulates and selects the first item again.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this normal?  Should I put the first dropdown into an updatepanel instead and have it trigger itself, and in its own trigger, populate the 2nd listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that changing the value in the second dropdown is causing a postback, which it then sets the value to the default or first value. Try setting the dropdown's AutoPostBack property to false and EnableViewState to true.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) instead.

EDIT:  You need to set your [UpdateMode](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/mref/P_System_Web_UI_UpdatePanel_UpdateMode.aspx)=Conditional and control when your UpdatePanel's should update, by calling UpdatePanel2.Update().

Comment: CascadingDropDown populates from a webservice, and I populate my controls in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once.
This is a problem for update panel plus dropdown autopostback
By default ViewState for page is stored,so you do not need to change ViewState for control.

First,Change your UpdatePanel's UpdateMode property to Conditional `UpdateMode="Conditional"`.This ensures that you can control postback since your dropdown always postback when you set **AutoPostBack** to true.

Second is in your method which you bind datasource into dropdown,after databinding is done.Update your panel by calling **Update** method of UpdatePanel `updPanel.Update();` by

```
dropdown.DataSource = source;//I presume
dropdown.DataBind();
updPanel.Update();
```

Hope this helps.